# WPF- TimePicker Binding to set date and time at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, timepicker

In my Wpf app, I've two TimePickers. I've used binding for them but their time is not updating. I also want to set selected date for these TimePickers.I tried to bind it as below. But, it won't work. Actual problem here is TimePickers are inside DataTemplate.

Here is xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
    <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" Value="{Binding StartValue, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
    <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" Value="{Binding EndValue, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Binding with properits in C#:

```
    private DateTime _dateTime1;
    public DateTime StartValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateTime1;
        }
        set
        {
            _dateTime1 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
            OnPropertyChanged("StartValue");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _dateTime2;
    public DateTime EndValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _dateTime2;
        }
        set
        {
            _dateTime2 = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
            OnPropertyChanged("EndValue");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String time)
    {
        if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(time))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(time));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion
```

Please suggest some ideas?

Comment: in which class are the properties declared. Do you use a ViewModel? Where do you use your EditableDataTemplate? Pleas add the information to your question

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in your Output window when debugging?

Comment: @Jehof Yes. These properties are declared inside my ViewModel. In my xaml, I've two DataTemplates. Out of which 'EditableDataTemplate' is one.

Comment: @Richard Not getting any errors. Only TimePickers are not updating. Other controls works fine.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the setters can you confirm if they are ever hit? I'm going to hazard a guess that they aren't, so the property value will never be set (and therefore never notified, and the TimePicker will never update). What happens f you set the value of these properties from somewhere else, like the constructor of your VM?

Comment: @Richard You are right. It's not setting value for _dateTime1 and _dateTime2. Can you post code to set date and time for them in constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set your values in your property setters which will never get called so the property value will never be set (and therefore never notified, and the TimePicker will never update).

Why not try setting the properties in the constructor of your ViewModel. I'm not sure what your ViewModel is called but here goes:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

public MyViewModel()
{
    StartValue = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
    EndValue = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
}

private DateTime _dateTime1;
public DateTime StartValue
{
    get
    {
        return _dateTime1;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_dateTime1.Equals(value)) return;
        _dateTime1 = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("StartValue");
    }
}

private DateTime _dateTime2;
public DateTime EndValue
{
    get
    {
        return _dateTime2;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_dateTime2.Equals(value)) return;
        _dateTime2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EndValue");
    }
}

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String time)
{
    if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(time))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(time));
    }
}

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
}
```

This will ensure the PropertyChanged events are fired for both properties and as long as your binding is correct you will see the values update.

Comment: Is it necessary to write RelativeSource in xaml of TimePicker?

Comment: What is the DataContext of your Window set to? This needs to be set to your viewmodel. Do other bindings on your Window work?

Comment: Yes. It's set to ViewModel only in my constructor. Other bindings works.

Comment: Then what if you take away the RelativeSource, do you get any binding errors?

Comment: With RelativeSource, it updates StartValue and EndValue of each entry which I don't want. So, I removed it and put UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged there. But, I'm not getting any binding errors.

Comment: Im a bit confused over what you are trying to do, if you have a single VM instance, each instance of this template will bind to the same properties, is that not what you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35411/discussion-between-richard-and-user2622971)